# How to separate Sphinx chapters within a single part into different files?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sections, toctree

I'm using the wonderful Sphinx tool to create some documentation and I'm trying to keep the codebase in a modular form by separating chapters of the same part  into separate files. ([See here for definitions of 'chapter' and 'part'.](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#sections))

I've tried to do this using two files, `test1.rst`:

```
######
Part 1
######

*********
Chapter 1
*********

Section 1
=========
Test Content 1.
```

and `test2.rst`:

```
*********
Chapter 2
*********

Section 2
=========
Test Content 2.
```

They are included in `index.rst` like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   test1
   test2
```

However, upon build, Chapter 2 doesn't get nested within Part 1. Why is this? Is there any way of doing this without having to create a script to append them into a single file like the example below?

Example:

```
######
Part 1
######

*********
Chapter 1
*********

Section 1
=========
Test Content 1.

*********
Chapter 2
*********

Section 2
=========
Test Content 2.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like the [`include`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include) directive is what you are looking for. The included file's content is parsed and included at the point of the directive.

test1.rst:

```
######
Part 1
######

*********
Chapter 1
*********

Section 1
=========
Test Content 1.

.. include:: test2.rst
```